# {"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"} at Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: asp.net, iis, excel-interop

I am trying to create an excel file using the below code in an ASP.Net web applcation.
The code works normally when I run from visual studio, but an exception occur **workbook.Close** command when I deploy the application on IIS and run the deployed version.

```
Excel.Application exc = null;
try
{
    exc = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbooks workbooks = exc.Workbooks;
    Excel._Workbook workbook = workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    Excel._Worksheet worksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
    Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    Object[] data = new Object[] { "" };
    range.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, range, data);
    workbook.Close(true, p_sTempFileName, null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
finally
{
    if (exc != null)
        exc.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jayendra/5443/

check the section where it says "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

hope it works.

Comment: more info about this excel setting, it was first provided by an mvp a.k.a Kaboro rashad!!

Comment: yeah i know this guy!! he's the best!!:P

Comment: @Boomer the post has been moved... could you fix it?

Comment: @JuanPabloContreras try this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/how-to-create-excel-file-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

In the code:

- A1 should not be zero;
- A1 should be > 0;
- `Range rng = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range((object)worksheet.Cells[1, 1],            (object)worksheet.Cells[3,3])`