# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Occurs Only after deploying to IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, iis

I'm trying to create an excel file and save it in the file system.

Here is how do I do it :

```
private string CreateExcel(List<ExcelResult> list, string fileName) {
    // Create the file in the server
    string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Media/Temp/Excel/" + fileName + ".xls");
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("SerialNo", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));

    foreach (ExcelResult item in list) {
        dt.Rows.Add(item.SerialNo, item.Code);
    }

    Application app = new Application();
    Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;
    ws.DisplayRightToLeft = false;
    ws.Name = "GiftCards";

    ws.Cells[1, 1] = "SerialNo";
    ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Code";
    int rowcount = 2;

    foreach (DataRow datarow in dt.Rows) {
        rowcount += 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            ws.Cells[rowcount, i] = datarow[i - 1].ToString();
    }

    try {
        wb.SaveAs(path);
        wb.Close();
        app.Quit();

        return fileName + ".xls";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception thrown -> " + ex.Message);
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

The error occurs only when I deploy the app on the IIS and there isn't any problem in local (iis express).

Any Idea?

Comment: Please provide exception details, and which line caused the problem.

Comment: @Aria it happens on IIS, so I don't have more details around it, But I'm sure that it happens in `wb.SaveAs(path);`

Comment: So there are some ways to know Ex details, 1- you should write log details in `txt` file 2- check `Event Viewer` in windows 3- turn on error handling in `web.config` like `customErrors mode="On"`, anyway find a way to know more about that exception.

Comment: @Aria I'm afraid but it doesn't have any `inner exception` message.

Answer (score 0):

After finding this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7008370/6679820) and reading this [Article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/how-to-create-excel-file-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/) provided by [Bommer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642573/boomer)

I found out that it was a problem around the server itself which solved by going through the structure provided in the article.